# Different GDBs, different debugging behaviors

Tags: macos, gdb, homebrew

**Background**

I am trying to debug a C++ code that uses some personal dynamic libraries. I am using Mac OSX, but I am not using llvm/clang to compile my code nor the libraries. At the moment, I am using the GNU g++ compiler (4.7) provided by homebrew.

**The problem**

I have two choices of debuggers in this environment: the gdb version provided by Mac Developer Tools (GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824)) and the gdb installed with homebrew (GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5.1). I would prefer to use the latter, but when using it, it shows many important variables as *optimized out*.

For example, this is an extract of the output of my program using gdb 7.5.1:

```
Breakpoint 1, MWE::Outputs (this=<optimized out>, time=<optimized out>)
    at /Users/ynet/temp/mwe.cpp:203
203     cout << "example" << endl;
(gdb) p this
$1 = <optimized out>
```

While gdb 6.3.50 shows:

```
Breakpoint 1, MWE::Outputs (this=0x100601080, time=0.64300000000000046) at /Users/ynet/temp/mwe.cpp:203
203     cout << "example" << endl;
(gdb) p this
$1 = (MWE * const) 0x100601080
```

Both programs are identical (i.e. it's the same executable); it has been compiled with the homebrew g++-4.7 and not the llvm/clang compiler provided by Apple Developer Tools.
Unlike questions regarding the *optimized out* results of gdb, I have checked that I am compiling with '-O0'  (my current flags are '-O0 -g -ggdb')

**Question**

Why do I get two different behaviors of gdb in this case and what should I do in order to use the most recent gdb version without the optimized values?

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I get two different behaviors of gdb in this case and what should I do in order to use the most recent gdb version without the optimized values?

It is clearly a bug for GDB to print `<optimized out>` for un-optimized code.

You should try to reproduce this with GDB built from trunk, create a minimal test case that shows the problem, and file a bug bugzilla.